# Why am I getting an illegalBlockSizeException when trying to decrypt this message?

Tags: java, exception, encryption

I am creating a server (Responder B) and client (Initiator A) which will exchange encrypted messages that will be decrypted on the receiving end. However, when I send an encrypted message from responder B to initiator a, I am getting the "Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with the padded cipher" error.

Here is the server/Responder B code:

```
public class ResponderB {
    protected static String masterKey = "NETWORK SECURITY";
    protected String identityA;
    protected String ciphertext;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private DataInputStream in;
    
    public ResponderB(int port, String ciphertext) {
        this.ciphertext = ciphertext;
        try {
            
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Responder started");
            System.out.println("Waiting for initiator ...");
            
            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Responder accepted");
            
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            
            String line = "";
            
            //System.out.println("ResponderB ciphertext: "+this.ciphertext);
            
            try {
                line = in.readUTF();
                this.identityA = line;
                System.out.println("Identity Recieved");
                System.out.println("Initiator Identity: "+this.identityA); 
                       
                this.identityA = encrypt(this.identityA, masterKey);
                this.ciphertext = this.identityA + " " + this.ciphertext;
                System.out.println("Message Two Ciphertext in bytes: "+this.ciphertext.getBytes());
                System.out.println("Message Two Ciphertext: "+this.ciphertext);
                out.writeUTF(this.ciphertext);
            
            }catch(IOException i){
                System.out.println(i);
            }   
        
        System.out.println("Closing connection");
        
        //close connection
        socket.close();
        in.close();
        
        }catch(IOException i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        
    }

    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String sessionKey = "SESSION";
        String ciphertext1 = ""; String ciphertext2 = "";
        String identityB = "RESPONDER B";
        
        
        ciphertext1 = encrypt(identityB, masterKey);
        ciphertext2 = encrypt(sessionKey, masterKey);
        
        String cleartext = ciphertext1 + " " + ciphertext2;
        
        ResponderB initiator = new ResponderB(6666, cleartext);
    }}
```

This is the client/initiator a code:

```
public class InitiatorA {

    private String identity = "INITIATOR A";
    private String masterKey = "NETWORK SECURITY";
    private String ciphertext, plaintext, temptext, sessionKey;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;

    public InitiatorA(String address, int port) {
        // try to establish a connection
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            //ready the input reader
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // String to read a message from the input
            String line = "";
            String buffer = "";

            //line = input.readLine();    // Reads line from keyboard 
            System.out.println("Cleartext of message 1: " + this.identity);
            out.writeUTF(this.identity); // writes it to the output stream

            buffer = in.readUTF();
            this.ciphertext = buffer;
            System.out.println("The received ciphertext of message 2: " + this.ciphertext);
           
            String[] tokens = this.ciphertext.split("\\s+");
            for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
                this.plaintext = this.plaintext + decrypt(tokens[i], this.masterKey);
            }
            
            
            System.out.println("The decrypted message 2: " + this.plaintext);
            
        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InitiatorA responder = new InitiatorA("127.0.0.1", 6666);
    }}
```

Finally, these are the encrypt and decrypt methods I am using, the algorithm to encrypt and decrypt the messages is DES, and I am using a custom key (masterKey) that is being converted to a secret Key from a string, One thing I noticed is that the byte [] of the ciphertext being transmitted is changing from the server to the client-side, but the actual text in the cipher text remains the same.

Another exception I am getting is the: "
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption." But I don't see how a bad key would be in place here since the same string is being used on the server and client-side.

```
public static String encrypt(String plain, String key) {
        String plaintext, ciphertext = "", plaintext1;
        byte[] plaintextByte, plaintext1Byte, ciphertextByte, keyByte;
        plaintext = plain;
        try {
            keyByte = key.getBytes();
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey desKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyByte));

            plaintextByte = plaintext.getBytes();

            Cipher desCipher;
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);

            ciphertextByte = desCipher.doFinal(plaintextByte);
            ciphertext = new String(ciphertextByte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeySpecException i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return ciphertext;
    }

public static String decrypt(String cipher, String key) {
        String plaintext = "", ciphertext, plaintext1="";
        byte[] plaintextByte, plaintext1Byte, ciphertextByte, keyByte;
        try {
            keyByte = key.getBytes();
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey desKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyByte));

            Cipher desCipher;
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
            
            plaintext1Byte = desCipher.doFinal(cipher.getBytes());
            plaintext1 = new String(plaintext1Byte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeySpecException i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return plaintext1;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: One thing to note is: you get your encryption from a string with "getBytes()" but this way you don't specifiy an **Charset-encoding**, you should always use getBytes(StandardCharset  e.g. UTF8) on both sides. Second: your masterkey is of length: 16 bytes that does not fit to a DES-key (should be of 8 bytes length).

Comment: I added StandardCharsets.UTF_8 to each getBytes(), unfortunately it still does not work however, for the masterkey, I am required to use the one I have, the weird thing is i am able to encrypt using the master key but not able to decrypt using it

Comment: Ciphertext is not a string, and conversion from randomized bytes to string is almost certain to lose information. You should use base 64 encoding/decoding instead, and that's only when text is actually required (which it usually isn't). The key should not be text either. Besides these encoding mistakes, your code is utterly insecure for at least 3 reasons. From your cipher string I'd remove DES, ECB and PKCS5Padding :|